# Sequential attributes of snapped lines

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes

I'm a stormwater engineer using QGIS and I need to do some mapping of ~2000 stormwater pipes. As part of this I need to assign unique pipe identifiers to each pipe with each pipe system labelled in sequential order from the upstream to downstream end, and each section of the network will have a different prefix. See below for an example.

Do you have a way of doing this without needing to go through individually and naming each one?

The lines will be snapped together if that helps at all.

This bit of code seems like it is getting close but it's only renaming "ID" of the line with the smallest id() which makes me wonder if its an issue with not preserving the order of the ordered_list .

```py
# Define function 
def find_connected_line(start_vertex, selected_features):
    for feature in selected_features:
        if feature.geometry().vertexAt(-1) == start_vertex:
            return feature
    return None

# Get the selected features
layer = iface.activeLayer()  # Assuming the layer is active
selected_features = layer.selectedFeatures()

# Initialize variables
ordered_features = {}
current_vertex = None
feature_index = 1

# Find the first line with no other lines connected to its first vertex
for feature in selected_features:
    first_vertex = feature.geometry().vertexAt(0)
    connected = False
    for other_feature in selected_features:
        if other_feature != feature and other_feature.geometry().vertexAt(-1) == first_vertex:
            connected = True
            break
    if not connected:
        current_vertex = first_vertex
        ordered_features[feature.id()] = feature
        selected_features.remove(feature)
        break

# Follow the connected lines in sequential order
while selected_features:
    next_line = find_connected_line(current_vertex, selected_features)
    if next_line is not None:
        current_vertex = next_line.geometry().vertexAt(0)  # Updated to start of next line
        ordered_features[next_line.id()] = next_line
        selected_features.remove(next_line)
    else:
        break

# Update the 'ID' attribute based on the order they are joined
layer.startEditing()
for feature_id, feature in ordered_features.items():
    feature['ID'] = f'A{feature_index}'
    layer.updateFeature(feature)
    feature_index += 1

layer.commitChanges()

# Refresh the map canvas to see the changes
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

[image: pipe schematic example]

Comment: Not without extensive coding experience. I've done something similar before, only going up from the outflow, that was in C# using ArcObjects (Esri ArcMap). I used an implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm to identify paths as they branch and sorting longest to shortest, longest being A, the outflow starting at 1 and increasing for each intersection moving contraflow, next longest B and so on. It wasn't easy. A shortcut method involving networking is probably your best bet, not automatic but less user intensive.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Get the selected features
selected_features = iface.activeLayer().selectedFeatures()

# Function to get the start and end points of a line
def get_start_end_points(line):
    return line.geometry().asMultiPolyline()[0][0], line.geometry().asMultiPolyline()[-1][-1]

# Create a spatial index for the selected features
index = QgsSpatialIndex()
for feature in selected_features:
    index.addFeature(feature)

# Find the first line
first_line = None
for feature in selected_features:
    start_point = get_start_end_points(feature)[0]
    possible_connections = index.intersects(QgsRectangle(start_point, start_point))  # Check for intersecting features
    if len(possible_connections) == 1:
        first_line = feature
        break

# If no lines are selected or no valid first line is found, exit the script
if first_line is None:
    print("No valid starting line found. Exiting script.")
    exit()

# Initialize a list to store the sorted lines
sorted_features = [first_line]

# Sort the selected features by their spatial order
while len(sorted_features) < len(selected_features):
    last_feature = sorted_features[-1]
    last_end_point = get_start_end_points(last_feature)[1]
    
    found_next = False
    
    for feature in selected_features:
        start_point, end_point = get_start_end_points(feature)
        
        if last_end_point == start_point and feature not in sorted_features:
            sorted_features.append(feature)
            found_next = True
            break

    if not found_next:
        break

# Assign sequential IDs to the features
for i, feature in enumerate(sorted_features):
    feature['ID'] = f'A{i + 1}'

# Update the layer with the modified features
iface.activeLayer().dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({f.id(): {1: f['ID']} for f in sorted_features})

# Refresh the layer
iface.activeLayer().triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Kindly explain how this code snippet helps in solving the problem.